# SQL injection in parametrized stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-injection, parameterized

I have a stored procedure :

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployeesTest2 
    @LastName nvarchar(50), 
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) 
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        FirstName, LastName, Department
    FROM 
        HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory
    WHERE 
        FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName
        AND EndDate IS NULL;
GO
```

It will cause SQL injection if I supply `@LastName = '' OR '1' = '1' --''`

I am new to SQL injection. I need some advice on how can i protect it

Comment: No, it will **not** be vulnerable to SQL injection - it will just search for someone by that last name (and most likely not find anyone) ... SQL injection only happens when you concatenate together SQL statements and user input in your own code

Comment: If the query was "select * ", then the user can see all the information ( which he will not be allowed. He will be allowed to see information based on where clause ). Isn't it a security fall??

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you're asking .... there's no `SELECT *` in this code, and with that value for `@LAstName` there won't suddenly be a `SELECT *` either ......

Comment: Ok let me clear. If there something like SELECT * from ..... where FirstName = parameterOfFirtName AND LastName = parameterOfLastName ... and the value for parameterOfFirtName would be '' OR '1' = '1' --'' . In that case the user might see all the information regardless of where clause. I was asking if I should be aware of this too.

Comment: No, as long as you use **parametrized queries** (as you do), you're safe. No SQL injection. SQL injection only happens when you yourself are constructing SQL statements from fragments of SQL and user input and you mix that without using parameters

Answer (score 2):

There is crucial a difference whether you have a stored procedure which contains a parameterized statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc @Param NVARCHAR(50) AS
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col = @Param;
GO
```

Or a stored procedure that builds the statement dynamically in a string:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc @Param NVARCHAR(50) AS
    DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(500)
    SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col = ''' + @Param + '''';
    EXEC @Query;
GO
```

With the former stored procedure, the data parameter is clearly distinguishable from the code.

However, with the latter stored procedure, the value of `@Param` is incorporated into the resulting SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col = '<value of @Param>'
```

And if the value of `@Param` isn’t formatted properly, it may end the string literal prematurely and parts of the parameter value may not be interpreted as intended, i. e., not as a string.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I did not get what does it mean by " the data parameter is clearly distinguishable from the code." for the 1st procedure. Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: @YeasinAbedinSiam The variable does not get interpolated and replaced by its value in opposite to the second case. The parser actually recognizes `@Param` as a variable and will use its value only on execution. Have a look at [Bill Karwin’s presentation *Sql Injection Myths and Fallacies*](http://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies), slide 47 and following.

Comment: ohh..now i understood clearly..thank you very much!! :)